# Journey Builder Send times

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Is there a way to adapt the send time of emails within a journey post activation?  I want to be able to test out different times as we go to get data on what the optimal time to reach this audience is.

My impression is, that it's only possible to do that by creating a new version - which wouldn't update anything for existing subscribers in the previous version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to adjust the wait activities of a running journey version.

One workaround would be stopping the journey and ejecting the subscribers and reinjecting them into a new version that only contains the part of the journey the subscribers didn't went through. However this will only work if you inject your subscribers once and not for journeys where subscribers are continually injected.

Comment: When I activate that journey, is that inherently the 'Time Of Send' for the 1st email?  So, if I have an automation audience that is set to run daily @ 8:05am and Activate the journey @ 8:00am - that group will run through the journey on the following day?

Comment: If your first email is also the first activity, then the time of the first contact entry is the time of send. So if the journey entry is triggered by an automation at 08:00am this will be the time of the first send.